# Flutter Isolate.run with multiple arguments

Tags: flutter, dart, background-process, dart-isolates

I want to implement something like, when I tap on a download button, it will download the data from the API and store it in the database. Currently this code is working fine, though I haven't added any error handlers,

Suddenly, I noticed about `Isolate.run` function, which does a lot of work in the back.

I want to replace this workable code with the Isolate.run

But I have no idea about how to do it.

Is this code good enough? If not, then which things I need to implement here?

I've a class Named, `MyIsolate`, which is look like something,

```dart
class MyIsolate {
  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static Future<void> start(void Function(List<Object>) entryPoint,
      RootIsolateToken token, int randomId, SendPort uiSendport) async {
    final receivePort = ReceivePort();
    final isolate = await Isolate.spawn(
      entryPoint,
      [receivePort.sendPort, token, randomId],
    );

    receivePort.listen((message) {
      print('message $message');
      if (message == 'done') {
        print('done');
        receivePort.close();
        uiSendport.send('done');
        isolate.kill();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

From the UI, I'm using this like,

```dart
  FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              //randomID between 1 and 10
              final apiID = 1 + Random().nextInt(10 - 1);
              receivePort = ReceivePort();

              MyIsolate.start(
                isolateEntryPoint,
                RootIsolateToken.instance!,
                apiID,
                receivePort.sendPort,
              );
              //receivePort.asBroadcastStream()
              receivePort.asBroadcastStream().listen((message) {
                print('message in ui $message');
                if (message == 'done') {
                  //show snackbar
                  receivePort.close();
                }
              });
            },
            tooltip: 'Download Background',
            child: const Icon(Icons.download),
          )
```

And this is my code that executes inside the Isolate,

```dart
void isolateEntryPoint(List<Object> args) async {
  final SendPort sendPort = args[0] as SendPort;
  final RootIsolateToken token = args[1] as RootIsolateToken;
  final apiID = args[2] as int;

  BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized(token);

  // Make the network call with Dio
  Dio dio = Dio();
  Response response =
      await dio.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/$apiID');

  DriftIsolate isolate;

  // Parse the API response into Dart objects
  final parsedData = UserDto.fromJson(response.data);
  print(parsedData.toString());

  DatabaseConnection connection = DatabaseConnection.delayed(() async {
    isolate = await backgroundConnectionIsolate();
    return await isolate.connect();
  }());

  MainDatabase db = MainDatabase.connect(connection);
  UsersDAO dao = UsersDAO(db);
  final response1 = await dao.insertUser(parsedData);
  print(response1);
  // Send the parsed data back to the main isolate
  if (response1) {
    sendPort.send(parsedData.toString());
  } else {
    sendPort.send(null);
  }
  //close
  await connection.executor.close();
  db.close();
  sendPort.send('done');
}
```

I've tested with `Isolate.run()`, but I can't understand how to pass the arguments, as it throws an error.

I also searched in ChatGPT. Maybe I'm not telling the ChatGPT in the proper way, how to do it.

Comment: Re *"Maybe I'm not telling the ChatGPT in the proper way"*: ChatGPT is a pathological liar, so it isn't so surprising.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yeah! But still, it's better in some ways than guessing code in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Isolate.spawn(), you pass arguments directly to the entry point. In Isolate.run(), you need to use closures to pass arguments. You encapsulate your function and its arguments within a closure and pass the closure to Isolate.run().

Modify the entry point for Isolate.run() by creating a closure that includes your original isolateEntryPoint function and its arguments.
Ensure that your closure correctly handles the necessary operations and communication with the main isolate.

```
// Closure that includes your isolate entry point and its arguments
void Function() createIsolateFunction(SendPort sendPort, RootIsolateToken 
 token, int apiID) {
  return () {
    isolateEntryPoint(sendPort, token, apiID);
   };
 }

 // Modified start method to use Isolate.run
    static Future<void> startWithIsolateRun(
 SendPort uiSendPort, RootIsolateToken token, int randomId) async {
final receivePort = ReceivePort();
final closure = createIsolateFunction(receivePort.sendPort, token, 
  randomId);

 await Isolate.run(closure);

  receivePort.listen((message) {
    // Handle messages and potentially kill the isolate
  });
}

// Usage
MyIsolate.startWithIsolateRun(receivePort.sendPort, 
RootIsolateToken.instance!, apiID);
```

In this example, createIsolateFunction creates a closure that includes your original entry point and its arguments. This closure is then executed in a new isolate by Isolate.run().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy